# load wicket sample project with maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, wicket

I am looking for wicket project example so I can learn how to create my web project with wicket. When I go to Wicket and look for a sample project to download, I reach to this page: http://wicket.apache.org/learn/projects/ and I cannot find any download. The only thing I found is the dependency using maven. How can I use this dependency in order to load the project in my IDE?

I am using Intellij.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go to the [quick start page](http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html) and copy the maven comand into a commandline (you need to have maven installed). Running the command will create a small project, containing all  you need to get started. with `mvn jetty:run` you can run the project.

Intellij Idea can open maven project (file->'import project from external project' ...)

hope that helps.

Comment: Should I install maven or this tool installed already with intellij?

Comment: @Naor: haveing maven installed is always a plus. And you will need it to run the command from the quickstart. Later own, you may not need it much, as intellij bring a good maven support with it

Comment: You'd better install it, there is OSes shipped with maven (OS X is one of them), but AFAIR, IntelliJ does not include it.